# Convert arraylist object to byte[]

Tags: c#, arrays

I have araylist object named  list, here i want to convert my arraylist object to byte[], while doing the below coding its giving an error: "At least one element in the source array could not be cast down to the destination arraytype"
my coding:

```
 byte[] obj= new byte[list.Count];
     list.CopyTo(obj);
```

here my array list objects returns report data from ssrs reports.what i want to do here to solve this issue.

Comment: Well the error message is pretty clear - it's expecting your `list` to be *byte* values, not objects containing report data. It sounds like you want serialization of some form... are these objects using your own classes? What sort of serialization are you expecting?

Comment: How do you expect it to cast ReportData or whatever to bytes? Do you want them as memory-bytes?

Comment: @MarcGravell from the description it is probably ArrayList (;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this (this will show you where can be a problem)

```
        List<object> list = new List<object>();
        list.Add((byte)1);
        list.Add((byte)0);
        list.Add("wtf");
        list.Add((byte)1);
        byte[] obj = list.OfType<byte>().ToArray();
        if(obj.Length!=list.Count)
        {
            //Exception, not all objects in list is 'byte'
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the ArrayList contains items of type `byte` then use such syntax:

```
byte[] obj = (byte[])list.ToArray(typeof(byte));
```

Otherwise what you want is not clear, as objects can't be cast to byte just like that so please explain better.

Comment: he will have same exception, if there is one or more element not byte type, btw for me `list.CopyTo(obj);` more nice.