# Cast object array to byte array

Tags: c#

I have an object array containing array of a different type that is not known at compile time, but turns out to be `int[]`, `double[]` etc.

I want to save these arrays to disk and I don't really need to process their contents online, so I looking for a way to cast the `object[]` to a `byte[]` that I then can write to disk.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use binary [serialization and deserialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b85344hz.aspx) for [Serializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx) types.

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

BinaryFormatter binary = BinaryFormatter();
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(file))
{
    bs.Serialize(fs, objectArray);
}
```

Edit: If all these elements of an array are simple types then use BitConverter.

```
object[] arr = { 10.20, 1, 1.2f, 1.4, 10L, 12 };
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    foreach (dynamic t in arr)
    {
        byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(t);
        ms.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: My implementation is forced to convert to a byte array before data can be written, as the actual writing is done by a different class.

Comment: Use `MemoryStream` instead of `FileStream`. You could add sample data in your post.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will do something else than just serializing the values. I have tried this, and for an object array containing two integers, I get a 39 byte stream!

Comment: Well you may use `BitConverter.GetBytes(for all simple types)` method.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it the old fashioned way.

```
static void Main()
{
  object [] arrayToConvert = new object[] {1.0,10.0,3.0,4.0, 1.0, 12313.2342};

  if (arrayToConvert.Length > 0) {
     byte [] dataAsBytes;
     unsafe {
        if (arrayToConvert[0] is int) {
           dataAsBytes = new byte[sizeof(int) * arrayToConvert.Length];
           fixed (byte * dataP = &dataAsBytes[0]) 
              // CLR Arrays are always aligned
              for(int i = 0; i < arrayToConvert.Length; ++i) 
                 *((int*)dataP + i) = (int)arrayToConvert[i];
        } else if (arrayToConvert[0] is double) {
           dataAsBytes = new byte[sizeof(double) * arrayToConvert.Length];
           fixed (byte * dataP = &dataAsBytes[0]) {
              // CLR Arrays are always aligned
              for(int i = 0; i < arrayToConvert.Length; ++i) {
                 double current = (double)arrayToConvert[i];
                 *((long*)dataP + i) = *(long*)&current;        
              }
           }
        } else {
           throw new ArgumentException("Wrong array type.");
        }
     }

     Console.WriteLine(dataAsBytes);
  }
}
```

However, I would recommend that you revisit your design.   You should probably be using generics, rather than object arrays.

Comment: I like this one, but I would create MemoryStream instead and use BinaryWriter to write to it...  Nice, clean, tightly packed.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578310/convert-arraylist-object-to-byte):

```
List<object> list = ...
byte[] obj = (byte[])list.ToArray(typeof(byte));
```

or if your list is complex type:

```
list.CopyTo(obj);
```

Comment: There is no overload of `ToArray` that takes arguments.

Comment: From the doc-link it seems that `OfType` filters, and doesn't convert. Indeed running your snippet produces an empty `obj`.